# Add a code branch to a single workspace in Hudson

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

Does anyone know how to add a subversion branch to hudson and have it build the whole branch? It seems that I would have to make a workspace for each branch/app. So could I just add the branch to a workspace and have hudson build each directory? Hope this isnt a stupid question.

This is a java enviroment so mostly maven and ant builds. Could I make a mass pom.xml file to have it build each directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the projects that I have are just a collection of small projects (libraries). To build them I created a simple pom.xml that contained every subfolder as a module. Works fine for me.

Alternatively, you can use the [M2 Extra Steps Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/M2+Extra+Steps+Plugin) to call all the poms separately and still have the comfort of a maven job. More straight forward would be a freestyle project, here you can define all other targets.

All have the disadvantage that you need to configure the projects explicitly. If you don't wanna do that, write a shell script that parses the directory tree and calls maven with the pom files found.